# Pointer to object and destructor

Tags: c++, object, pointers, destructor

I am trying to understand why my code doesn't use destructor of class Name. In fact I write two classes. First one called Name and a second called Person that have a pointer to object Name. What I don't understand is why the program doesn't called to the destructor of Name, because I think when I write "new" I create a new object so it has to call to the destructor of class Name before closing program.

Can you explain what wrong in my understanding. Thanks !

```
class Name
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    Name(string name) : name(name) { cout << "Hello " << name << endl; }
    ~Name() { cout << "See you soon " << name; }
};
class Person
{
private:
    Name* myname;
public:
    Person(string name) { myname = new Name(name); }
    ~Person() { cout << "Exit" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Person("Marc");
    Person("Alex");
}
```

Comment: when you write `new` you are explicitly saying "I will call `delete` later". Others say that a kitten dies, not sure about that.

Comment: When you use `new`, "it" doesn't have to do anything. The responsibility for cleaning up is all yours.

Comment: Because the object is never destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a memory leak here, because you create a new instance of `Name` here

```
Person(string name) { myname = new Name(name); }
```

but you never delete it. This is the reason why the destrcutor of `Name` is never called.

To avoid this you can use an `std::unique_ptr` or an `std::shared_ptr`, which will automatically handle the lifetime of such an object.

```
std::unique_ptr<Name> myname;
Person(string name) { myname = std::make_unique<Name>(name); }
```

An alternative is to delete the object in your destructor, but in `C++` you should avoid direct handling of dynamic raw pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Name
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Name(std::string name) : name(name) { std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl; }
    ~Name() { std::cout << "See you soon " << name << std::endl; }
};
class Person
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Name> myname;

public:
    Person(std::string name) { myname = std::make_unique<Name>(name); }
    ~Person() { std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Person("Marc");
    Person("Alex");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (The reason you should avoid `new` and `delete` is because it's so easy to make mistakes. Normal pointers are perfectly fine though.)

Comment: @user253751, I added `dynamic raw pointers` instead, to make it clearer.

Comment: Actually you should avoid **pointers** when you don't have a reason to use pointers. This example doesn't need pointers at all.

Comment: @user253751, While this may be true for the given sample, this may be a stripped down example for the sake of posting on SO.

Answer (score 1):

As **myname** object in Person's class is a pointer. For every pointer there must be a delete statement to deallocate the memory.

Replace Person's class Destructor as:

```
~Person() { 
        cout << "Exit" << endl;
        delete myname;
    }
```

Comment: worth mentioning that this fixes the leak in OPs current code, but `Person` is still broken due to ignoring the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)